# 'an introduction of' or 'the introduction of'?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

If I want to say that a problem can be solved by means of introducing some constraints, do I use a definite or an indefinite article for the word *introduction* ?

> (a) The problem can be solved through **the** introduction of additional constraints.
>
> (b) The problem can be solved through **an** introduction of additional constraints.

To me it doesn't look like a possessive form which would require a definite article, however, *the* sounds more familiar to me with the word *introduction*. I am not sure though.

I have the same doubts about a phrase *removal*:

> (a) This entails **the** removal of element 47 from X.
>
> (b) This entails **a** removal of element 47 from X.

Comment: On both examples, I'd use `the`.  While neither is technically incorrect, `the` makes it sound stronger, as though you _are_ introducing additional constraints, rather than just that somebody _should_.  In English, usually go with your gut.

Comment: On all these I'd use *by* + gerund: *by introducing additional constraints*, *by removing an element*. Go with the verbiest form that works.

Comment: The short answer is you use "the".

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is based on whether you're talking about "any solution" or "a definitive solution".

As stated by Glorfindel, the articles here aren't necessary and may be omitted, so the decision is whether you wish to leave room for other solutions (yours is one solution among many) which would be best served by using ***an***, or not (yours is the *proper* solution) which would be best served by using ***the***.

This may also be dependent upon the tone of the document in which this phrase will be used. If you're writing a persuasive argument, use the definite article. Otherwise, the choice is up to your personal style.